# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation and UIViewController Rotation predicament

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, rotation

I've got a problem.
I've an `UIImageView` and i do some rotation to it with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()`.
Not problem with that.
But when i do a rotation with my `UIViewController` (portrait to landscape and/or inverse).
My `UIImageView` is modified strangely.

Its frame become change from :`CGRectMake(50.f, 50.f, 150.f, 150.f)` 
to a frame like :`CGRectMake(50.f, 123.2f, 1004.56f, 1530.456f)`

I realize that changes happens when I do UIViewController rotation when i've done a rotation on my `UIImageView` not equal to 0, 90, 180, or 270

I think it's because the `UIViewController` change the rect of the `UIImageView` but how inhibit
that comportement

---

Unfortunately my view move/change visually. 
That's my problem and why I'm talking about that here...
I spoke about the `frame` property because I notice it changed strangely (and randomly) and even if I changed it after to my original `frame`. The view doesn't seem 'listen' to it.
I hope I am well.
Anyone for a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

If you set a view's `transform` property to anything but the identity matrix (which you must have done in order to rotate it), the `frame` property becomes undefined and should be ignored. This is noted in the documentation. Is it just the frame property that goes wrong or is the view moving/changing visually in some unexpected way as well?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your description, but it sounds as if your `UIImageView` is a subview of the view owned by your `UIViewController`.  Unless you have a reason to not manage it this way, I'd suggest setting the `UIImageView` struts and springs (i.e., its `autoresizingMask`) to surface the desired behavior and then allow the parent view to reposition/resize the `UIImageView`.